# ChromeDriver failing to acces the select

Tags: java, select, selenium, webdriver

I am trying force the ChromeDriver to select an item from the select box. However its failing on the line

```
    Options = select.getOptions();
```

Strange is, that in below code, the `getText();` method prints out all items in the select:

```
  productChoooser.getText() = ...
  BASE 2013
  BASE 2014
```

but still I get exception... Code which is trying to click the item in select box:

```
    List<WebElement> Options;
    WebElement productChoooser = driver.findElement(By.id("mainForm:aucPanelId:1:product"));
    System.out.println("productChoooser.getText() = " + productChoooser.getText());
    Select select = new Select(productChoooser);
    Options = select.getOptions();
    String product = "BASE 2013";
    for (WebElement option:Options){
        System.out.println("option.getText() = " + option.getText()); 
       if(option.getText().equals(product)){
           option.click();
       }
    }
```

Does anyone know how to avoid it? I tried to update the Chrome and `chromedriver.exe` to the newest version, but without any success...

Stack Trace:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:  (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 47 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.16.1', revision: '15405', time: '2012-01-05 12:30:12'
>   System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0_20'
>   Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:147)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:113)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:435)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:231)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElements(RemoteWebElement.java:161)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElementsByTagName(RemoteWebElement.java:227)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByTagName.findElements(By.java:313)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElements(RemoteWebElement.java:146)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.getOptions(Select.java:70)
>       at com.deutscheboerse.testing.RegulationTest.selectProduct(RegulationTest.java:53)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:199)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        WebElement select = webDriver.findElement(selector);
        List<WebElement> optionList = select.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
        for (WebElement option : optionList) {
            if (option.getText().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("your value")) {
                option.click();
                break;
            }
        }
```